# what is the best way to remove certain objects from a nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-object

I have the following nested object:

```
{
  "cards": {
    "1": {
      "x": 247,
      "y": 213,
      "properties": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "a",
        "intros": {
          "intro_0": {
            "id": 1,
            "cardId": 1
          },
          "intro_1": {
            "id": 2,
            "cardId": 1
          },
          "intro_3": {
            "id": 24,
            "cardId": 1
          }
        },
        "exits": {
          "exit_0": {
            "id": 1,
            "cardId": 1
          },
          "exit_1": {
            "id": 22,
            "cardId": 1            
          }
        },
        "mixins": {
          "mixin_0": {
            "id": 23,
            "cardId": 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "x": 762,
      "y": 187,
      "properties": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "x",
        "intros": {
          "intro_0": {
            "id": 1,
            "cardId": 1
          },
          "intro_1": {
            "id": 263,
            "cardId": 1
          }
        },
        "exits": {
          "exit_0": {
            "id": 1,
            "cardId": 1
          },
          "exit_1": {
            "id": 2,
            "cardId": 1
          }
        },
        "mixins": {
          "mixin_0": {
            "id": 3,
            "cardId": 1
          }
        },
      }
    },
    "4": {
      "x": 1200,
      "y": 187,
      "properties": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "j",
        "intros": {
          "intro_0": {
            "id": 1,
            "cardId": 1
          },
          "intro_1": {
            "id": 276,
            "cardId": 1
          }
        },
        "exits": {
          "exit_0": {
            "id": 1,
            "cardId": 1
          },
          "exit_1": {
            "id": 2,
            "cardId": 1
          }
        },
        "mixins": {
          "mixin_0": {
            "id": 3,
            "cardId": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to go through the object to extract only the first of the "intro" and the first of the "exit" and modify the original object so that it only contains these with the rest of the data. Or what is the same, I would like to remove all the "intros" except the first one and all the "exits" except the first one.
To extract the values I want I have made 3 for in ... but when it comes to modifying the original object I think I've made it too complicated and there must be some easier way.

```
const cards: any = Object.values(data.cards);

      for (const indexCard in cards) {
        if (cards.hasOwnProperty(indexCard)) {
          const card = cards[indexCard];
          const cardIntros = card.properties.intros;
          for (const introIndex in cardIntros) {
            if (cardIntros.hasOwnProperty(introIndex) && introIndex === 'intro_0') {
              const firstIntro = cardIntros[introIndex];
              const cardsExits = card.properties.exits;
              for (const exitIndex in cardsExits) {
                if (cardsExits.hasOwnProperty(exitIndex) && exitIndex === 'exit_0') {
                  const firstExit = cardsExits[exitIndex];
                }
              }

            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Does anyone see an easier way to remove the "intros" and "exits" I want to remove, in order to generate a new object that only contains the desired "intros" and "exits"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is actually tougher than it seems as your `intros` and `exits` is an object instead of an ordered array. Should we be assuming that intro and exit entries will always end in `_index`, e.g. `exit_0`.  I assume as well 0 is your starting index in naming these entries? If you created this structure I would suggest in future using an array of objects.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer all "intros" and "exits" end in an ordered index starting with 0. It's the only guide I saw. The data was given to me. I figured it wouldn't be that easy because I couldn't find any method to remove what I wanted directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create recursive function that will check if the current value is object and then also if the some of the keys of that object is equal to the keys provided by the parameter. If it does include that key it will delete other keys from that object. This will work for any level of nesting.

```js
const data = {"cards":{"1":{"x":247,"y":213,"properties":{"id":1,"name":"a","intros":{"intro_0":{"id":1,"cardId":1},"intro_1":{"id":2,"cardId":1},"intro_3":{"id":24,"cardId":1}},"exits":{"exit_0":{"id":1,"cardId":1},"exit_1":{"id":22,"cardId":1}},"mixins":{"mixin_0":{"id":23,"cardId":1}}}},"3":{"x":762,"y":187,"properties":{"id":1,"name":"x","intros":{"intro_0":{"id":1,"cardId":1},"intro_1":{"id":263,"cardId":1}},"exits":{"exit_0":{"id":1,"cardId":1},"exit_1":{"id":2,"cardId":1}},"mixins":{"mixin_0":{"id":3,"cardId":1}}}},"4":{"x":1200,"y":187,"properties":{"id":1,"name":"j","intros":{"intro_0":{"id":1,"cardId":1},"intro_1":{"id":276,"cardId":1}},"exits":{"exit_0":{"id":1,"cardId":1},"exit_1":{"id":2,"cardId":1}},"mixins":{"mixin_0":{"id":3,"cardId":1}}}}}}

function first(data, props = []) {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    if (typeof v == 'object' && v != null) {
      if (Array.isArray(v)) {
        r[k] = v.map(e => first(e, props))
      } else {
        const value = { ...v }
        const check = props.some(p => Object.keys(v).includes(p))

        if (check) {
          for (let i in value) {
            if (!props.includes(i)) {
              delete value[i]
            }
          }
        }

        r[k] = first(value, props)
      }

    } else r[k] = v
    return r;
  }, {})
}


const result = first(data, ['intro_0', 'exit_0'])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This will not work if you have an array in your data. Then you could either modify original data or use some deepClone method and then modify that clone object.

Comment: you could just edit your answer to include your comment :)

Comment: @NenadVracar I'm checking your solution but "const check = props.some(p => Object.keys(v).includes(p))"  I get an error back "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: I am guessing you are trying on some other data, can you post it?

Comment: At some point `v` is null or undefined, that is why you get the error.

Comment: I've forgot that `typeof null` is object. You can just modify to this ` if (typeof v == 'object' && v != null) {` like this https://jsfiddle.net/gpr58xw6/.

Comment: @NenadVracar it works perfectly!!!  now I have to understand everything!!!! thank you so much!!

Comment: Basically if the value is object then it will check if some of the keys of that object exists in props array which you provide as param and then it will remove all other properties from that object that are not included in the props array and pass it that result to next recursive call.

Comment: If you want this to also work on arrays you could add something like this https://jsfiddle.net/pw5uhj2L/